# Почему в этом выражении порядок выполнения операций не гарантируется?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum;
char *p;
/*...*/
sum = (((sum * 10) - '0') + ((*(p++)) = (getchar())))
```

С точки зрения черновика C2x.

**UP**
Ссылка на черновик стандарта: [open C202x draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf)
Приведённый пример находится на странице 5.1.2.3 Program execution, Example 7.

Comment: ¿При чем тут порядок выполнения, когда тут везде обращение к неиницилизированным переменным?

Comment: Специально для умных поправил фрагмент.

Comment: Всё ещё не инициализированны

Comment: Для особо догадливых повторю - смотреть нужно на комментарий.

Comment: Я этот документ (черновик C2x) не видел, но могу предположить, что  они хотят разрешить  вычислять операнды  в произвольном порядке (с целью упростить реализацию параллельных вычислений)

Comment: А минусуют этот вопрос, очевидно, люди не компетентные и недалекие ...

Comment: @avp, там написано, что в этой ситуации не ясно, когда выполнится p++ или getchar(), что мне не очень понятно.

Comment: @Грузчик, ссылочку на черновик и это место в нем не приведете? Возможно речь о том, что возможные побочные эффекты вызова функций (изменение нелокальных переменных (в данном случае изменение `p` внутри вызова getchar)) не рассматриваются и можно тогда инкрементировать `p` в каком угодно порядке

Comment: Столько копий сломано вокруг побочных эффектов в выражения, что я для себя решил, что никогда не буду помещать несколько побочных эффектов в одно и то же выражение. Одно присвоение - один оператор, два присвоения - два оператора и т.д.. Не надо тратить силы на решение ребусов вместо решения задач.

Comment: @avp, добавил в тело вопроса.

Comment: @Грузчик, прочел. Imho они *не говорят*, что *неясно...*. Imho они говорят, что имплементатор *может перемещать* **вызовы функций** (т.е. он может предполагать, что побочных эффектов нет) и действия над явно не участвующими в вычислении результата выражения переменными (там  это `p++`) куда ему удобно (из соображений эффективности (?)) между явно заданными sequence points (the ;).